# Does this serve as a counterexample to my statement?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

My claim: $$\sup(cA) = c\sup(A) \implies c \ge 0$$

$$P \implies Q$$

Now, I say that,

Let $A = \{1\}$ and $c = -1$. Then, $\sup(cA) = -1 = c\sup(A)$. This holds true for $c = -1$.

$P$ is true while $Q$ is false. Hence, $P \implies Q$ must be false.

Does my logic hold with this?

Comment: Yep you've constructed a valid counter-example

Comment: @CyclotomicField should it not hold for all $A$ to be valid?

Comment: Your P is incompletely specified. Is it a specific $A$ or for all $A$?

Comment: You must specify the domain of $c$, and what elements $A$ can take.

Comment: @copper.hat it is supposed to be general, for all $A$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implied in the comments, we need to know how you are quantifying over $A$, which is not clear from your notation or your comments.

$\forall c \forall A. (\sup(cA) = c \sup(A) \implies c \ge 0)\;\;$ is false as you state. In fact this is false whenever $A$ is a singleton.

$\forall c((\forall A.\sup(cA) = c \sup(A)) \implies c \ge 0)\;\;$ is true. To see this let $A = \{-1, 2\}$. Then $c\sup(A) = 2c$, while we have:

$$
\sup(cA) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l}
2c & \mbox{if $c \ge 0$} \\
c & \mbox{if $c < 0$}
\end{array}\right.
$$